# Give a simple answer: Which is correct: Was the pasta cooking or Were the pasta cooking?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number

Give me a simple answer please: Is it Was the pasta cooking or Were the pasta cooking? Which is correct because I had a debate with my teacher over it. (I'm from Europe)

Comment: It's *was the pasta cooking*. 'Pasta' is a mass noun.

Comment: Use a plural verb only if *pasta* is the plural of *pastum* or *paston*.  Neither of these words exists, as far as I know.

Comment: If you use "were" then you need to pluralize - "Were the pastas cooking?" - and this means you at least have multiple pots of pasta, or separate bowls of it, perhaps in a restaurant setting, or you are cooking more than one type, also in separate dishes.  Even in these cases, you can simply not pluralize it - "Was the pasta cooking" is almost always fine

Answer (score 1):

'Pasta' is not a plural noun, it is a *mass noun* or an 'uncountable' noun. It is treated as a singular noun, and you should therefore use 'is'.

It doesn't how much pasta you have - you have 'some pasta'. An individual piece of pasta would be referred to either as a 'piece' of pasta, or by some other suitable noun such as a 'strand' or 'string' of spaghetti.

This may be different from Latin languages - the term 'spaghetti', for example, is a Latin plural form (just as 'cacti' is the plural of cactus) and technically one single strand of spaghetti should be known as a 'spaghetto'; however, this is unknown to the majority of native English speakers and we just don't use the term.

Comment: Yes - _spaghetti_ is plural to the Italians, but English speakers think of it as a substance.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, that's what I said.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Obviously I don't mean the cuisine is Latin - I mean that the word takes the Latin plural form rather than pluralising it with -s or -es.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That would be misleading for at least two reasons. Firstly, we're speaking about the English word, even though it may be the same in Italian, that is irrelevant. Latin is the root language that influences the English here on the choice of plural. Secondly, modern latin languages like French and Italian do not necessarily follow that same rule - for example, neither Italian nor French uses 'cacti' as the plural for cactus.